# Cannot go to the line of the reference

Tags: linux, vim, cscope

I recently installed **cscope** Vim plugin to make it easier to jump through code, but the main functionality - go to line, does not work. 
I have F2 key mapped to "Find all references". When I select a function call for example, and press F2, I get the list of all the references, and the first reference is usually the function definition. When I type the line number and press Enter, nothing happens, and it is supposed to jump to the line I typed in. What could possibly be the problem here? Do I need to make some additional changes to my vimrc file to make the jumping possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I type the line number and press Enter, nothing happens, and it
>   is supposed to jump to the line I typed in

You actually should type the number that appears on the first column. The cscope usage is explained in detail at `:help cscope-commands`. It also provides the following example:

```
    :cscope find 0 DEFAULT_TERM

    Executing this example on the source code for Vim 5.1 produces the
    following output:

    Cscope tag: DEFAULT_TERM
       #   line  filename / context / line
       1   1009  vim-5.1-gtk/src/term.c <<GLOBAL>>
         #define DEFAULT_TERM (char_u *)"amiga"
       2   1013  vim-5.1-gtk/src/term.c <<GLOBAL>>
         #define DEFAULT_TERM (char_u *)"win32"
       3   1017  vim-5.1-gtk/src/term.c <<GLOBAL>>
         #define DEFAULT_TERM (char_u *)"pcterm"
       4   1021  vim-5.1-gtk/src/term.c <<GLOBAL>>
         #define DEFAULT_TERM (char_u *)"ansi"
       5   1025  vim-5.1-gtk/src/term.c <<GLOBAL>>
         #define DEFAULT_TERM (char_u *)"vt52"
       6   1029  vim-5.1-gtk/src/term.c <<GLOBAL>>
         #define DEFAULT_TERM (char_u *)"os2ansi"
       7   1033  vim-5.1-gtk/src/term.c <<GLOBAL>>
         #define DEFAULT_TERM (char_u *)"ansi"
       8   1037  vim-5.1-gtk/src/term.c <<GLOBAL>>
         # undef DEFAULT_TERM
       9   1038  vim-5.1-gtk/src/term.c <<GLOBAL>>
         #define DEFAULT_TERM (char_u *)"beos-ansi"
      10   1042  vim-5.1-gtk/src/term.c <<GLOBAL>>
         #define DEFAULT_TERM (char_u *)"mac-ansi"
      11   1335  vim-5.1-gtk/src/term.c <<set_termname>>
         term = DEFAULT_TERM;
      12   1459  vim-5.1-gtk/src/term.c <<set_termname>>
         if (STRCMP(term, DEFAULT_TERM))
      13   1826  vim-5.1-gtk/src/term.c <<termcapinit>>
         term = DEFAULT_TERM;
      14   1833  vim-5.1-gtk/src/term.c <<termcapinit>>
         term = DEFAULT_TERM;
      15   3635  vim-5.1-gtk/src/term.c <<update_tcap>>
         p = find_builtin_term(DEFAULT_TERM);
    Enter nr of choice (<CR> to abort):

    The output shows several pieces of information:
    1. The tag number (there are 15 in this example).
    2. The line number where the tag occurs.
    3. The filename where the tag occurs.
    4. The context of the tag (e.g., global, or the function name).
    5. The line from the file itself.
```

You are supposed to type a number between 1 and 15; any other just cancel the command.